# Difference in instances

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, tomcat7

I have a Java servlet (Java 1.6.0.29) running in Tomcat 7.0 all in Windows.  SSL has been set up to encrypt information between the servlet and databases.  Also, I have a test instance of the servlet and a Live instance.  I am using SoapUI to simulate web requests and Wireshark to check the encryption.  The problem is in the Test servlet communication is encrypted fine in both TO AND FROM a SQL Server database server.  However, in the Live instance only some of the communication TO and FROM the same SQL Server database server is encrypted.

Could someone please tell me what differences I should check in the instances?

I have checked that each servlet instance has the following XML in the APPLICATIONS web.xml file

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Thanks in advance

AJFarroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered how to resolve this.

Firstly, obviously I was attempting to get the instances working on my desktop PC, but this had my Eclipse development environment on it also, and I realised there may be additional context.xml files with the Eclipse workspace.  I amended these to match my Tomcat's context.xml file and this processed the issue a little further.

Secondly, I had two isntances of the same servlet, i.e. Test and Live (Web service end point URL's slightly different) running within the same Tomcat and so obviosuly the same machine.  I found this works okay when SSL is NOT implemented but when SSL is implemented only ONE instance of the servlet can be running.

Perhaps someone knows a way around this.  If so let me know.

Thanks to all who viewed

Regards

AJF